# Moving Java Application to Azure PaaS Function App Loader Writing To Azure File - Use Azure Storage SDK or Leave Oracle JDK as is?

Tags: java, azure

Completely new to Azure.

Moving currently standalone Oracle JDK 1.8 Java application to 
Azure PaaS Function App Loader.

Application is to write to Azure File.

Application currently writes to file on local disk using 
java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.File(java.lang.String pathname)).

Have been told no change to this is required.

Except I should change it to Oracle JDK 11 (for support, update reasons etc.)

Write will occur using SMB interface. (What is that?)

Is this correct?

Or should I use the Microsoft Azure Libraries for Java?

In particular: com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.FileOutputStream?

Which is better (if both will work) i.e. performance, better supported?

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: [Server Message Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write file to Azure File, Yes, you need to use Azure Storage SDK to call Storage File methods. You could refer to this [doc](http://sourceFile) and this is [library](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/file/package-summary.html) about storage file.

And here is a simple code to write a file to Azure Storage File, you could refer to this.

```
 @Test
public void writeFile(){

    try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

        CloudFileShare share=fileClient.getShareReference("storagefileshare");

        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

        File sourceFile = File.createTempFile("sampleFile", ".txt");
        System.out.println("Creating a sample file at: " + sourceFile.toString());
        Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sourceFile));
        output.write("Hello Azure!");
        output.close();

        CloudFile cloudFile=rootDir.getFileReference(sourceFile.getName());
        cloudFile.uploadFromFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you want to know how to develop a Java Azure Function, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij).

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks - Where do I download the Azure Java SDKs? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ takes me in circles. Do I have to use the SDKs from Azul Systems? Which is fine.

Comment: Mostly we use maven to download the jar package, here provides three ways to get the package.https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java#download  If you want to develop Azure program local, mostly you need SDK to call methods, you could refer to doc , there is a "How to " link, if the service supports java you could find it and there are sample codes , you could follow that.